# Uncaught SyntaxError with day countdown script

Tags: javascript, html, date, countdown

So I have this script that I got from a website, which I modified to the best of my limited JS knowledge. Surprisingly it did not work, as it gave an error on the line I'll highlight.
Here's the script that I put inside the  of my HTML:

```
<script>
  var before = "Event before"
  var current = "Today is the date set in countdown"
  var montharray = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

  function countdown(yr, m, d) {
      var today = new Date()
      var todayy = today.getYear()
      if (todayy < 1000)
        todayy += 1900
      var todaym = today.getMonth()
      var todayd = today.getDate()
      var todaystring = montharray[todaym] + " " + todayd + ", " + todayy
      var futurestring = montharray[m - 1] + " " + d + ", " + yr
      var difference = (Math.round((Date.parse(futurestring) - Date.parse(todaystring)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 1)
      if (difference == 0)
        document.getElementByID("days").innerHTML = "0";
      else if (difference > 0)
        document.getElementByID("days").innerHTML = +difference + ;
    }
    //enter the count down date using the format year/month/day
  countdown(2015, 01, 01)
</script>
```

It's supposed to replace the contents of a bold tag inside a paragraph, but apparently the issue is with the actual script and not with the ID or the function.

Any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: `document.getElementByID("days").innerHTML = +difference+;` isn’t valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (difference > 0)
    document.getElementByID("days").innerHTML = difference;
```